# Tensorflow load_weights() works in Google Colab but fails locally

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a Tensorflow 2.0 project and am running into an interesting error. My project works with no errors when I run it in Google Colab. However, when I run the code locally, I get the following error:

`ERROR:tensorflow:Couldn't match files for checkpoint` followed by the file path to the appropriate checkpoint.

This error occurs when I call `model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(CKPT_DIR))`. Here is the traceback (on my Windows machine):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\shakespeare_lstm.py", line 159, in <module>
    run_model(SEED)
  File ".\shakespeare_lstm.py", line 147, in run_model
    model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(CKPT_DIR))
  File "E:\Github Repos\ShakespeareLSTM\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 181, in load_weights
    return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
  File "E:\Github Repos\ShakespeareLSTM\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1139, in load_weights
    if _is_hdf5_filepath(filepath):
  File "E:\Github Repos\ShakespeareLSTM\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1449, in _is_hdf5_filepath
    return (filepath.endswith('.h5') or filepath.endswith('.keras') or
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

This happens on my Windows machine that runs Python 3.6.8 and my MacOS machine that runs Python 3.7.2. The Google Colab runs Python 3.6.9 and throws no errors and executes as expected. All of them have Tensorflow 2.0.0.

My [GitHub repo](https://github.com/brunofreeman/ShakespeareLSTM) has the project code.

The only difference in the code that I have on Google Colab is the ROOT variable for the file paths (`ROOT = os.path.join("/", "content", "drive", "My Drive", "Colab Notebooks", "Shakespeare LSTM")`) and the following two additional lines (not directly after one another in the actual code):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Another difference is that the Google Colab notebook is set up to use a GPU, while my local machines are not. The model was trained on Google Colab, and the checkpoint files were downloaded.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this code works on Google Colab and not locally?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same version of Tensorflow on both machines? I think your machine might be running Tensorflow 1.x

Comment: @aminrd I just did `print(tf.__version__)` to confirm and they are indeed running 2.0.0